# How to run @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint

Tags: angular, eslint, tslint, angular-schematics

I'm trying to switch an Angular project from TSLint to ESLint, following the instructions in [angular-eslint Github repo](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint).

I ran `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics` which added the following dependencies to my package.json:

```
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "1.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.3.0",
    "eslint": "7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
```

Also, ran `npm install` to ensure these are all installed.

Now I'm instructed to run:

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint --remove-tslint-if-no-more-tslint-targets --ignore-existing-tslint-config
```

However, this results in errors:

```
Unknown option: '--remove-tslint-if-no-more-tslint-targets'
Unknown option: '--ignore-existing-tslint-config'
```

When I remove these options, I get another error:

```
Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.
```

It seems like this angular-eslint schematic was not installed properly. However, I'm a complete novice regarding these schematics. I must be missing something obvious here.

Using @angular/cli 10.2.3.

Answer (score 10):

In case you don't know which is the name of your project when the CLI asks you

`Which project would you like to convert from TSLint to ESLint?`

it can be found in the `angular.json` under the `projects` attribute (normally on line 8)

Comment: Thanks, this is where I was stuck. The project name is the key of your `"projects"` entry ... in my case it was `"ng"`.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the Angular version of your project because it **install a different version of `@angular-eslint/schematics` for different angular versions**

**Steps** will be:

**A. Add @angular-eslint to your project:**

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
```

If you have an Angular 12 project (without tslint), you’re done!

**B. For migration from tslint Angular 11 or 12, run the following:**

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint --remove-tslint-if-no-more-tslint-targets
```

(Use: `--ignore-existing-tslint-config` flag only if you want to ignore old tslint configuration)

**If you are on Angular 9 or 10**, an older version of the schematic gets installed and the convert command differs slightly. You may want to prioritize upgrading Angular before converting to ESLint. But if you really want to upgrade linting first, use this command:

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint <project-name-here>
```

[Detailed blog for tslint to eslint migration](https://medium.com/@bhavinmatariya99/painless-migration-of-tslint-to-eslint-angular-b25da240320c)

Comment: Thx this was what I needed: "If you have an Angular 12 project, you’re done!" - no need to run convert

Answer (score 1):

If you're migrating an existing project then you should run either

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint
```

or

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint {{YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_GOES_HERE}}
```

instead of

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint --remove-tslint-if-no-more-tslint-targets --ignore-existing-tslint-config
```

as per the guidelines https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#step-2---run-the-convert-tslint-to-eslint-schematic-on-a-project

Comment: In that case I get `Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.` error, as I already pointed out.

Comment: What is your global angular cli version?

Comment: Both local and global are 10.2.3

Comment: Ideally it should work. I have also migrated to eslint in angular version 10 though my global angular cli version was 11.x.x. Try updating your global cli version to latest cli. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15290 adding it for reference.

Comment: No difference. Except that I also get a warning about a mismatch between local and global versions of angular-cli.

Comment: Perhaps I'll try again after having upgraded to Angular 11.

Comment: What should be used as YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_GOES_HERE ? I'm using my project directory name and getting Project 'my-project' could not be found in workspace.

Comment: Refer to your package.json, it has a key named `name`. That should be used as your project name.

Comment: I have updated my Angular version from 10 to 12. Also upgraded the eslint support without any error. If you guys are still facing any issue do let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands and see if it works:

```
npm install @schematics/angular@latest -g  
remove node_modules 
remove package-lock.json    
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular 14.  I ran

`ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@14`

Instead of

`ng add @angular-eslint/schematics`

And my linting started working using the command `ng lint`

Until then I was receiving error:

`NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id`