# Upgrading to EsLint: Error with angular.json (schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint)

Tags: angular, npm, eslint, tslint

I wanted to upgrade my project to ESLint and was following this tutorial:

https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2021/03/31/migrating-from-tslint-to-eslint/

I did the first command, `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics`, which worked. But then, after executing `ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint your_project_name` I got the following error:
[image]

I looked at this post already: [How to run @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165045/how-to-run-angular-eslint-schematicsconvert-tslint-to-eslint), but nothing about it helped.

This seems like an easy error to google but either I searched incorrectly or this really is some unusual problem. Obviously, I cannot delete the angular.json file. What might cause this?

My TsLint version: 6.1.0

My Angular version: 12.0.2

Note that I upgraded to Angular 12 a week ago, before it was Angular 11.

Comment: I need to migrate to eslint too but i dont know if it is best to update angular to the latest version before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the same upgrade in my project and added

```
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "defaultCollection": "@angular-eslint/schematics"
  },
```

in my angular.json manually.
After this I could continue with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this command from your root of your project (without the name of the project like you did)

`ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint`

I suggest to consider using this walkthrough instead https://www.bitovi.com/blog/angular-upgrades-painless-migration-from-tslint-to-eslint since it seems clearer from my point of view.